# I try to change setlog(true) but it doesnt change in if condition. it just prints false value. how to change it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React from 'react';

import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const SignIn = ()=>{

```
const [name , setName] = React.useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
const [isLogged , setLog] = React.useState(false);
 const submit = () =>
 {
    localStorage.setItem('name','Faateh');
    localStorage.setItem('password','Pass')
    if(name === localStorage.getItem('name') && password === localStorage.getItem('password'))
    {
        setLog(true);
        alert(isLogged);
    }
}

return(
    <div>
        <form>
            <label>Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" name = "username" value ={name} onChange = {e=> {setName(e.target.value)}} />
            <br />
            <label>Enter your password: </label>
            <input type="text" name = "password" value ={password} onChange = {e=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}} />
            <br />
            <button onClick = {submit}>submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

}
export default SignIn;

Comment: `isLogged` is a `const`. `const`'s don't change, that's their whole deal. Just because its a state variable doesn't mean it abides by different rules. It **will not change**; ever. What happens is you call the state updater and the **next render** (the `SignIn` function is called again) you will get a completely *new* `const` also called `isLogged` that holds the "updated" value. But you **will never** see the value updated during the same render.

Answer (score 1):

`useState` hook is asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately.

```
setLog(true);
alert(isLogged); //won't alert the new value
```

And if you want to get the updated state value then use `useEffect` hook with dependency array. React will execute this hook after each state update.

```
setLog(current => !current); //you have already defined the initial value as false, so we can just change it like this since it's a boolean

useEffect(() => {
    alert(isLogged);
}, [isLogged]);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but there are like 100 questions a day about this and we don't really need to answer every one. Instead it should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Okay @BrianThompson noted